# Error publishing flexdashboard as shiny app in R

Tags: r, shiny, publish, flexdashboard

I want to publish dashboard (flexdashboard) in shinyapp.io (R) but i constantly get the error:
"Error detecting locale: Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE): invalid multibyte string 3
(Using default: en_US)"

I researched and found nothing weird (non-ASCII) characters in my CSV.

My code runs well in local but when i try to publish it, never works.

I believe this is the critical part of the code:

```
---
title: "Airbus Defence & Space"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    social: ["linkedin"]
    vertical_layout: fill
    source_code: embed
    theme:
      version: 4
      primary: "#0000FF"
      navbar-bg: "#3ADAC6"
      base_font: 
        google: Prompt
      heading_font:
        google: Sen
      code_font:
        google: 
          # arguments to sass::font_google() 
          family: JetBrains Mono
          local: false
runtime: shiny
---

'''{r setup, include=FALSE}
 (a bunch of libraries)
# rsconnect::deploy app
 library(rsconnect)
 library(MASS)
 rsconnect::deployApp("C:/Users/kiker/Documents/RDashBoards/Airbus")
 rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='<username>',
              token='<token>',
              secret='<secret>')
(in my code i have my username, token and secret well written)

df <- read.csv('C:/Users/kiker/Documents/RDashBoards/airbus_raw_data.csv', encoding = "UTF-8")
#df <- load("df.RData")
data(df)
save(df, file = "df.RData")
#Init Variables
ord_df <- df %>% select(-matches("Del|Opr"))
names(ord_df) <- gsub("^Ord_", "", names(ord_df))
del_df <- df %>% select(-matches("Ord|Opr"))
names(del_df) <- gsub("^Del_", "", names(del_df))
opr_df <- df %>% select(-matches("Ord|Del"))
names(opr_df) <- gsub("^Opr_", "", names(opr_df))
aircraft <- ord_df %>% select(-matches("Reg|Cou|All"))
aircraft <- names(aircraft)
country <- sort(as.character(df$Country))
'''
```

I tried to set apart the .rmd file alone in a new folder as well, but really found no real good answer yet. Would appreciate a lot any help :)

This is how it looks now:

[Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLS7R.png)

I am expecing to see the dashboard published correctly in shinyapp.io, as now I can see the status is "running" but shows in the logger:

This is the whole Deploy log in R:

```
Preparing to deploy document...DONE
Uploading bundle for document: 9208413...Detecting system locale ... DONE
Deploying bundle: 7299931 for document: 9208413 ...
Waiting for task: 1306343830
  building: Building image: 8667442
  building: Installing system dependencies
  building: Fetching packages
  building: Installing packages
  building: Installing files
  building: Pushing image: 8667442
  deploying: Starting instances
  rollforward: Activating new instances
  unstaging: Stopping old instances
Document successfully deployed to https://enriquevillacoronado.shinyapps.io/Airbus_FlexDashBoard_Shiny/
Deployment completed: https://enriquevillacoronado.shinyapps.io/Airbus_FlexDashBoard_Shiny/
Warning message:
Error detecting locale: Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE): invalid multibyte string 3
 (Using default: en_US)
```

This is the .csv file:

[CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWL0a.png)